# Get value from form of ZK

Tags: zk, zk-grid

I have a problem with ZK!

This is my part of code:

```
<template name="model:group">            
            <group label="@load(each)" onClick="@command('viewGraph')"/>      
        </template>

        <!-- template for each element in model -->

        <template name="model" >                      
            <row >                          
                <label value="@load(each.hour)" />
                <label value="@load(each.value)" />                                         
            </row>                        
        </template>
```

When I click on group label I will create a graph with each.hour and each.value.

The problem is that these value is for all the table. I want that the graph get value only from clicked item.
Is it possible?

Comment: is this a duplicated question of your other question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is too vague, but I can suggest to try passing it through a BindingParam:

```
onClick="@command('viewGraph', item=each)"/>
```

but I'm not sure how you fill the underlying GroupsModel